# Set TargetObject in CallMethodAction as ViewModel from parent DataContext in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I'm creating a UWP app and so far I have been using the `CallMethodAction` to call methods from the ViewModel and it worked fine.

But now, I'm trying to use the same method for some buttons inside a `ListView`, and nothing happens when I click the button. The XAML code is:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:RoomPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<ListView x:Name="ActuatorListView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Room.Actuators}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Actuator">
        <Button x:Name="OnButton" Content="On">
           <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                  <Core:EventTriggerBehavior 
                           EventName="Click" 
                           SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=OnButton}">
                     <Core:CallMethodAction 
                        MethodName="OnButton_Click"
                        TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" />
                  </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
               </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have tried several ways to access the parent `DataContext`, but I found none working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your view model is actually not an **element**, you can't use it with `ElementName` for binding.

The right solution in your case would be to give your page a name (`x:Name="Page"`) and bind to its `DataContext`:

```
<Core:CallMethodAction 
   MethodName="OnButton_Click"
   TargetObject="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=Page, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: You're a xaml god. I really struggled with this trying (among other things) RelativeSource and AncestorType. If you could point me to any resources that gave you this understanding it would be appreciated.